# HOCR to HTML for visualizing

Tags: html, ocr, hocr

How to convert [hOCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOCR) to HTML for visualization?

If you open the raw hOCR file its only rendered as plain text (the elements are not positioned)

Answer (score 19):

There are different solutions for this task and I know these three:

- https://github.com/kba/hocrjs (overlay the hocr data over the image, different options how to show this)
  [image]
- https://github.com/not-implemented/hocr-proofreader (shows the image on the left and the hocr data on the right, possible to use for entering corrections)
  [image]
- https://github.com/ultrasaurus/hocr-javascript

All of these repos seem to consist mainly of some JavaScript and CSS files. The first two repos have both a link to some demo page where I have taken the pictures from.

The first one provides a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script which allows to inject this overlay on any suitable hocr website online and local (some configuration may be possible for that). I don't know how difficult it is to use the other solutins for your own hocr files, but it should be doable.

Answer (score 13):

> To add the interface to a plain hOCR file, add this line just before
> the closing `</body>` tag:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://unpkg.com/hocrjs"></script>
> ```
>
> Then open the html (hOCR) file in your browser.

[Source](https://github.com/kba/hocrjs)

Answer (score -8):

hOCR is HTML. You can view it in a web browser.